# Randomly initializing array using data pointer and size

Tags: arrays, pointers, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I see the following code in an NVidia matrix program and a program from my instructor.  When I look at this code I know I am doing something stupid, so could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?  **When I change the `rand` to a constant all I see is `0` for `data[i]`, and when I try to view `rand` I seem to see only about 4 different values.**

```
void randomInit(float* data, int size)  
{  
   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {  
   data[i] = 1;//rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;  
   printf("%d %d\n",i, data[i]);  
  }  
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` prints a formatted integer, try changing it to `%f`. [Here are other printf codes.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: [This](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) includes much more extensive documentation of the format codes.